# Nodemon not terminating Node.js process on macOS Big Sur when terminal window closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, nodemon, macos-big-sur

Ever since updating to macOS Big Sur version 11.0.1 (20B29), I have been having an issue where my Node.js processes are not being killed when I close the terminal window/tab (ZSH) when the server is started with nodemon. It appears they get switched to a new process, and that new process is kept alive.

For example if run `npm run dev`, the server starts normally:

```
...
[nodemon] starting `node dist/index.js`
server started on 5000
```

In another terminal tab I run `lsof -i tcp:5000` and see:

```
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    80310   <user>  27u  IPv6 ...99e293      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

Then when closing the terminal window running the Node server, I get the same message as prior macOS versions that states the processes in the tab will be terminated:

> "Do you want to terminate running processes in this window?
> Closing this window will terminate the running processes: npm, node (2)."

I choose 'Terminate', but the server is still accessible on localhost:5000. When I run `lsof -i tcp:5000` after closing the Node server tab/window the output shows:

```
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    80625   <user>  25u  IPv6 ...8a2293      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

So the port stays alive, but with a new PID and new IPv6 for the TYPE.

I should note 2 things:

1. If I use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to abort the process, it works as expected.
2. As soon as you update a file in the project, the process gets killed.

Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution?

Comment: It's done the same for me since I started using nodemon. I couldn't say *why* it happens, but, I make sure to `CTRL` + `C` every time now. Would be very helpful if there is a way to terminate it on close.

Comment: I am not 100% sure on this, but am 99% sure.  I've been working on this problem all morning and watching the processes come and go...or not go as the case may be.  I believe when you terminate a process by closing the shell, it is sending a SIGKILL event to the nodemon process.  Because SIGKILL is immediate, like running kill -9 pid xxxx, the event cant be intercepted by the program and propagated down to the child processes.  When you do a ctrl-C  to stop the process, it sends a SIGINT which can be intercepted and responded to by the child processes, which is why they shut down gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue. although i dont know the whats causing it and how to fix it from the root, there is one hack that you can use in this case which is instead of terminating your app using `ctl+c` you can use `ctl+\`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).